# Looping using pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I just got into learning pointers in C++ and I have been trying some different instances of using them to get a better understanding to them but there is some I go into that seems a little weird to me.

The code below is for looping through an array and what I assumed after it ran well that `arr` is just a pointer to the beginning of the array (because I could do `ptr = arr;`.

```
    int size = 3;
    int arr[size] = {50, 30, 20};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
        ptr++;
    }
```

But When I try looping through the same array but with using `arr` instead of `ptr` without assigning it to `arr` it gave me an error (lvalue required as increment operand) referring `arr++`.

This is the Code.

```
    int size = 3;
    int arr[size] = {50, 30, 20};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << *arr << std::endl;
        arr++;
    }
```

I don't understand why the first one work and the second doesn't although they are both pointers(as far as I know).

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. They are just converted to pointers.

Comment: You're making an invalid assumption because of an implicit conversion - `ptr = arr;` is equivalent to `ptr = &arr[0];`.

Comment: doesn't that mean that `arr` holds the address of `arr[0]` and what I know that this make `arr` a pointer (Pointers hold addresses).